# using __import__ on a module in a different directory python. django

Tags: python, django, models, python-import, importerror

I am attempting to import a model from another app in django.

The following attempt fails:

`from venueadmin.models import VenuePermissions`

fails how:

Python is not able to located VenuePermissions, i guess circular reference?

```
from django.apps import apps
suitscity = apps.get_model('suitsandtablesadmin', 'City')
```

fails how:

`raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet`.

so then I tried importing using `__import__`

```
suitscity = __import__('suitsandtablesadmin.models')
suitscity = getattr(suitscity, 'City')
```

and

```
 suitscity = __import__('suitsandtablesadmin/models')
 suitscity = getattr(suitscity, 'City')
```

all of which did not work because `City` is in a different directory `suitsandtablesadmin`

How can I make any one of these work?

The directory is as follows:

First I am trying to import models into my venue app models folder

```
suitsandtables 
   suitsandtables
      __init__
      permissions
      settings
      urls
      wsgi
   suitsandtablesadmin
      __init__
      apps
      models   <-- im trying to import a model from here
      serializers
      urls
      views
  suitsusers
      __init__
      apps
      models
      etc.....
  venueadmin
      __init__
      apps
      models
      views
  venues
      __init__
      apps
      models  <-- into here
      views
```

Comment: Please post the direcotry layout of the different apps you are trying to import (your app, `venueadmin`, and `suitsandtablesadmin`)

Comment: Your model name from your first attempt `VenuePermissions` does not match `City` from the rest of your attempts.

Comment: @Alasdair thanks Alasdair I was just using random values. That has no base on why the software is failing.

Comment: `from myapp.models import MyModel` should work, as long as `myapp` is on the Python path. If your values are made up, it's impossible to give any more help than that. If you've got a circular import, you should try to fix that, rather than using `__import__`.

Comment: when I use a real value `from suitsandtablesadmin.models import City` is the following error: unresolved reference

Comment: That sounds like it's not an actual Python error, but from your IDE. As long as the code runs, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: very fair @Alasdair thank you. I am going to test the code and see if we are in business